# List of index where corresponding elements of two lists are same

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, enumerate

I want to compare two different lists and return the indexes of similar stings.

For example, if I have two lists like:

```
grades = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D']
scored = ['A', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'D']
```

My expected output is:

```
 [0, 1, 4] #The  indexes of similar strings in both lists
```

However this is the result I am getting at the moment:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4] #Problem: The 2nd index being counted again
```

I have tried coding using using two approaches.

**First Approach:**

```
def markGrades(grades, scored):
    indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(grades) if item in scored]
    return indices
```

**Second Approach:**

```
def markGrades(grades, scored):
    indices = []
    for i, item in enumerate(grades):
         if i in scored and i not in indices:
         indices.append(i)
    return indices
```

The second approach returns correct strings but not the indexes.

Comment: Note that `if item in scored` passes if there is ANY match for that grade.  It doesn't look at the matching indices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) in *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
>>> grades = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D']
>>> scored = ['A', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'D']

>>> [i for i, (g, s) in enumerate(zip(grades, scored)) if g==s]
[0, 1, 4]
```

---

Issue with your code is that you are not comparing the elements at the same index. Instead via using `in` you are checking whether elements of one list are present in another list or not.

Because `'A'` at index `2` of `grades` is present in `scored` list. You are getting index `2` in your resultant list.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand with a clear explanation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic fails in that it doesn't check whether the elements are in the same position, merely that the `grades` element appears *somewhere* in `scored`.  If you simply check corresponding elements, you can do this simply.

Using your second approach:

```
for i, item in enumerate(grades):
    if item == scored[i]:
        indices.append(i)
```

The solution that `Anonymous` gives is what I was about to add as the "Pythonic" way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for correcting the second approach too, helped me clear the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the two lists in pairs (to avoid the over-generalization of finding a match anywhere in the other array) with `zip`

```py
grades = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'D']
scored = ['A', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'D']

matches = []
for ix, (gr, sc) in enumerate(zip(grades,scored)):
    if gr == sc:
        matches.append(ix)
```

or more compactly with list comprehension, if that suits your purpose

```py
matches = [ix for ix, (gr, sc) in enumerate(zip(grades,scored)) if gr == sc]
```